# Could not extend operators in F#?

Tags: f#, operators, extension-methods

```
module FSharp=
let Point2d (x,y)= Point2d(x,y)
let Point3d (x,y,z)= Point3d(x,y,z)
type NXOpen.Point3d with
    static member ( * ) (p:Point3d,t:float)= Point3d(p.X*t,p.Y*t,p.Z*t)
    static member ( * ) (t:float,p:Point3d)= Point3d(p.X*t,p.Y*t,p.Z*t)
    static member (+) (p:Point3d,t:float)= Point3d(p.X+t,p.Y+t,p.Z+t)
    static member (+) (t:float,p:Point3d)= Point3d(p.X+t,p.Y+t,p.Z+t)
    static member (+) (p:Point3d,t:Point3d)= Point3d(p.X+t.X,p.Y+t.Y,p.Z+t.Z)

let a=Point3d (1.,2.,3.)
let b=1.0
let c=a * b//error
```

> Error 15: The type 'float' does not match the type
>   'Point3d' E:\Work\extension-RW\VS\extension\NXOpen.Extension.FSharp\Module1.fs    18  13  NXOpen.Extension.FSharp

I want to extend the Point3d methods, some new operators. But it doesn't pass over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed it is possible.
There is a way to extend binary operators using the one and only and [little known ternary operator `?<-`](http://techneilogy.blogspot.com/2010/07/this-post-is-about-pair-of-f-operators.html). So in your case you can try this:

```
type SumPoint3d = SumPoint3d with
    static member        (?<-) (p:Point3d, SumPoint3d, t        ) = Point3d(p.X + t  , p.Y + t  , p.Z + t  )
    static member        (?<-) (t        , SumPoint3d, p:Point3d) = Point3d(p.X + t  , p.Y + t  , p.Z + t  )
    static member        (?<-) (p:Point3d, SumPoint3d, t:Point3d) = Point3d(p.X + t.X, p.Y + t.Y, p.Z + t.Z)
    static member inline (?<-) (a        , SumPoint3d, b        ) = a + b

type ProdPoint3d = ProdPoint3d with    
    static member        (?<-) (p:Point3d, ProdPoint3d, t        ) = Point3d(p.X * t, p.Y * t, p.Z * t)
    static member        (?<-) (t        , ProdPoint3d, p:Point3d) = Point3d(p.X * t, p.Y * t, p.Z * t)
    static member inline (?<-) (a        , ProdPoint3d, b        ) = a * b

let inline ( + ) a b =  a ? (SumPoint3d ) <- b
let inline ( * ) a b =  a ? (ProdPoint3d) <- b

let a=Point3d (1.,2.,3.) 
let b=1.0
```

Now you can try:

```
> let c=a * b ;;
val c : Point3d = Point3d (1.0,2.0,3.0)

>  2 * 3 ;;
val it : int = 6
```

Comment: Wait, how does this not break the regular `*` operator? `inline`-magic-ness allows for multiple functions with the same name and does method-overloading?

Comment: @Alxandr Yes, the ternary operator is overloaded and the ``*`` operator is redirected to the ternary, so it becomes also overloadedl. The overload is resolved at the call site by matching any specific signature or defaulting to the generic one which calls the regular ``*`` operator.

Answer (score 5):

If the `Point3d` type is declared in a separate assembly that you can't modify, then there is (unfortunately) no way to implement new overloads of the standard operators like `+` or `*`. The code in your question adds operators as extension methods, but the F# compiler doesn't search for extension methods when looking for overloaded operators.

If you can't modify the library, then there are three things you can do:

- Create a wrapper for `Point3d` that stores a value of `Point3d` and implements all the operators
  (but this is likely going to be quite inefficient)
- Define new operators that do not clash with the built-in ones. For example, you can use `+$` and `$+` for multiplication by scalar from the left and right. To declare such operator, you would write:

  ```
  let (+$) (f:float) (a:Point3d) = (...)
  ```
- Implement your own `Point3d` type that does all the work, possibly with a conversion function that turns it into `Point3d` when you need to call a library.

It is hard to tell which option is the best - the second approach is probably the most efficient, but it will make code look a bit uglier. Depending on your scenario, the option 1 or 3 may work too.

Comment: I agree with everything you say, but in certain cases it may also be appropriate to shadow the built-in operators rather than creating new non-clashing ones (e.g. in a scope where they do not need to be generic).

Comment: @Tomas: The (+$) operator is not accepted by F#, I don't know why.