# C# library overloads ^ operator. How to use ** instead?

Tags: f#, symbolic-math, computer-algebra-systems, symbolic-computation

The [Symbolism](https://github.com/dharmatech/Symbolism) library overloads arithmetic operators. Although it's written in C# I can use it from F#:

```
open Symbolism

let x = new Symbol("x")
let y = new Symbol("y")
let z = new Symbol("z")

printfn "%A" (2*x + 3 + 4*x + 5*y + z + 8*y)
```

the output:

```
3 + 6 * x + 13 * y + z
```

However, it also overloads `^` for powers. This of course doesn't play well with F#.

As a step towards a workaround, I exported a method group for powers:

```
printfn "%A" (Aux.Pow(x, 2) * x)
```

output:

```
x ^ 3
```

How can I overload `**` to use the `Aux.Pow` method group instead?

I can do something like this:

```
let ( ** ) (a: MathObject) (b: MathObject) = Aux.Pow(a, b)
```

And that does work for `MathObject` values:

```
> x ** y * x;;
val it : MathObject = x ^ (1 + y)
```

But `Aux.Pow` is overloaded for `int` as well:

```
    public static MathObject Pow(MathObject a, MathObject b)
    { return new Power(a, b).Simplify(); }

    public static MathObject Pow(MathObject a, int b)
    { return a ^ new Integer(b); }

    public static MathObject Pow(int a, MathObject b)
    { return new Integer(a) ^ b; }
```

Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: Can you not declare the same functions with the other operand types?

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet. I don't think F# operators (functions) overload the way C# methods do. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the trick described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971965/overloaded-inline-operators-in-f) like this:

```
open Symbolism

type MathObjectOverloads =
    | MathObjectOverloads 
    static member (?<-) (MathObjectOverloads, a: #MathObject, b: int) = MathObject.op_ExclusiveOr(a, b)
    static member (?<-) (MathObjectOverloads, a: #MathObject, b: #MathObject) = MathObject.op_ExclusiveOr(a, b)
    static member (?<-) (MathObjectOverloads, a: System.Int32, b: #MathObject) = MathObject.op_ExclusiveOr(a, b)

let inline ( ** ) a b = (?<-) MathObjectOverloads a b

let two = Integer(2)
let three = Integer(3)

two ** three

two ** 3

2 ** three
```

Unlike in the linked answer, we have to use the (?<-) operator because it's the only operator that can take 3 arguments instead of 2, and we need to overload on both the left and right side of the ^ operator

Comment: I've been using your `$` trick for some time now, and I'm curious – how did you know of `?<-`, and that it was necessary/appropriate here? Just attention to details in the language spec?

Comment: I learned the `$`trick from the other stackoverflow question I linked, and then I needed an extra parameter and I remembered ?<- took 3 arguments instead of 2. I went to the MSDN docs to see if there was another one, but it seems there isn't

Comment: @ildjarn, Gustavo Guerra: for more cases where you can use the ternary operator have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309620/could-not-extend-operators-in-f/8326906#8326906 . In F# 3.0 you can use static members instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034802/how-would-i-translate-a-haskell-type-class-into-f/8439395#8439395 , then you can have as many parameters as you need, FsControl project in Github uses this technique to emulate typeclasses.

Comment: @Gustavo, I tried to use static members instead of the ?<- operator, but couldn't get it to work, I got ambiguity errors, can you add another answer to this question that uses them instead?

Comment: Sure, here's an example with static members.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the same answer but without operators.
It works only in F# 3.0 and you can use any number of parameters.

```
let inline i3 (a:^a,b:^b,c:^c) = ((^a or ^b or ^c) : (static member threeParams: ^a* ^b* ^c -> _) (a,b,c))

open Symbolism

type MathObjectOverloads =
    | MathObjectOverloads 
    static member threeParams (MathObjectOverloads, a: #MathObject , b: int        ) = MathObject.op_ExclusiveOr(a, b)
    static member threeParams (MathObjectOverloads, a: #MathObject , b: #MathObject) = MathObject.op_ExclusiveOr(a, b)
    static member threeParams (MathObjectOverloads, a: System.Int32, b: #MathObject) = MathObject.op_ExclusiveOr(a, b)

let inline ( ** ) a b = i3(MathObjectOverloads, a, b)
```